# In which programming language/s are DirectX & OpenGL written?

Tags: opengl, directx-11

In which programming language/s are DirectX & OpenGL written (specially their core part like Kernel)?

Comment: https://www.freelancinggig.com/blog/2018/07/31/which-language-do-nvidia-software-developers-use/

Comment: At least for OpenGL, there is no 'official' implementation. OpenGL itself is a specification, which can be implemented in any language.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399676/how-does-opengl-work-at-the-lowest-level/6401607#6401607 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967073/how-interfacing-with-graphics-card-work-with-c-or-c/7967211#7967211 coudl be useful to read

Answer (score 3):

DirectX? Mostly a mix of C and C++

OpenGL? English, because OpenGL itself is just a specification document, written in technical prose. Most of the OpenGL **implementations** out there are also written in a mix of C and C++.

Answer (score 2):

Both OpenGL and DirectX are specifications of an API. They are not limited to one programming language. Different implementations might use different languages.

OpenGL is typically implemented by system libraries or provided by your graphics driver. If you are interested in the programming language you have to check which one is used by your specific implementation.

For DirectX the implementation on Windows might be the most common, but it is not the only one. For example emulators or the WINE runtime environment for windows programs on linux also implement the DirectX API (which in many cases is done by using the OpenGL implementation of the underlying host system).

Comment: To the person that downvoted my answer: Could you explain why? I would like to improve my answer if it contain inaccuracies. I just looked those things up again and couldn't find a mistake.